# Codeblocks does not print specific format

Tags: c, format, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
 double a, b, c, root1, root2;
 printf("Input the coefficient a => ");
 scanf("%lf", &a);
 printf("Input the coefficient b => ");
 scanf("%lf", &b);
 printf("Input the coefficient c => ");
 scanf("%lf", &c);
/* Compute the roots. */
root1 = (- b + sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
root2 = (- b - sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
printf("The first root is %8.3f\n", root1);
printf("The second root is %8.3f\n", root2);
return 0;
}
```

However, my output is

```
Input the coefficient a => 232
Input the coefficient b => 23
Input the coefficient c => 2
The first root is      nan
The second root is      nan
```

I'm just a beginner, is the format wrong?
Using codeblocks, writing in C.

Comment: The square-root of a negative number is `nan`.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: @lundin, perhaps a logical error instead? I shouldve stated i didnt understand what nun meant, and thought there was a bug instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
 double a, b, c, root1, root2;
 double temp;
 printf("Input the coefficient a => ");
 scanf("%lf", &a);
 printf("Input the coefficient b => ");
 scanf("%lf", &b);
 printf("Input the coefficient c => ");
 scanf("%lf", &c);
/* Compute the roots. */
temp = b*b-4*a*c;
if (temp >= 0) {
    root1 = (- b + sqrt(temp))/(2*a);
    root2 = (- b - sqrt(temp))/(2*a);
    printf("The first root is %8.3f\n", root1);
    printf("The second root is %8.3f\n", root2);  
} else {
    printf("There is no root!\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

> remember : load math library like this -> gcc "fileName" `-lm`

Comment: Please avoid code only answers as it's not immediately obivous what the changes were. Explain the solution instead.

Comment: add a temp variable : double temp; and then temp = b*b-4*a*c; and then check if it's value is positive of negative

Comment: @M.zanousi - Put some textual explanation in the answer. And please indent the code correctly. And please check the value returned by `scanf`

Comment: Thank you very much. i changed my code. can see that it produces nan as my variable temp is less than 0.
your code works great. 


`if (a == 0)

 {
     printf("You've entered 0.");
     printf("Only one root: %8.3f \n", -c/b);
 }


 else
 {

/* Compute the roots. */
root1 = (- b + sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
root2 = (- b - sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
printf("The first root is %8.3f\n", root1);
printf("The second root is %8.3f\n", root2);
 }`

my own edit. i dont understand how load math library in your format tho?
thanks for the quick replies!